# Issues with GAM (mgsv package): Dimensionality, numerical categorical variables and VIF

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

I'm performing gam (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mgcv/versions/1.8-40/topics/mgcv.package) on my data (180 rows and 44 columns [1 numeric dependent variable, 2 numeric 0/1 categorical independent variable and 41 numeric independent variables, all centred and standardized) but I suffered some issues in the process.

1 - I selected from high to low number of independent variables (columns, from all to 2) but, in the models with higher number of variables, error message appeared:

```
> for (i in 2:ncol(mydata)){
    variable__ <- c(variable__, variable_[i])}
> variable__ 
[1] "s(age)"       "s(wdstd_b_d)" "s(spo_b_d)"
> formula_ <- reformulate(termlabels = variable__, response = 'y')
> models[[THs]] <- try(gam(formula_ , data = as.data.frame(mydata)))
> variable__ <- c()
> formula_
y ~ s(age) + s(wdstd_b_d) + s(spo_b_d)
```

```
*"Error in gam(function, data = as.data.frame(mydata)) : Model has more coefficients than data".*
```

This error appears in models with 24 or more independent variable columns and works perfect in 22 or less (184 rows/subjects)

Checked, both (formula and data frame) have the same number of variables /columns. But this problem did not appear in low variable number models (generated within the same loop)(formula performed with reformulate() function). Maybe some idiosyncrasy of gam statistics?

2- Checking for multicollinearity with VIF (mgcv.helper::vif.gam(gam_model)), models with categorial variables generates this error:

```
> model_1 <- gam(formula_, data = as.data.frame(mydata))
> car:::vif(model_1)
|          |       GVIF  |Df  |GVIF^(1/(2*Df))|
|----------|-------------|----|---------------|
|age       |72791236433  |0   |          Inf  |
|wdstd_b_d |72791236433  |0   |          Inf  |
|spo_b_d   |72791236433  |0   |          Inf  |
```

```
> mgcv.helper::vif.gam(model_1)
A tibble: 0 x 1
... with 1 variable: vif <dbl>
```

But with models which includes a categorical variable I obtained this error:

```
*"Error in apply(X = X[, selected_col], MARGIN = 2, var) : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length"*
```

Never before I have problems dealing with this format of categorical variables and VIF in lm models, and I couldn't solve it.

3 - If I factorize my categorical variables (as recommended in https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/03/how-to-solve-common-problems-with-gams/) to try to solve this problems, function broke different in the same line of mgcv.helper function (https://github.com/samclifford/mgcv.helper/blob/master/R/vif.gam.R), and different error appeared:

```
*"Error in `[.data.frame`(X, , selected_col) : undefined columns selected"*
```

This error appears because factorized categorical variables (here, *postpref*) appears as example in summary(my_model), and function can't find variable:

```
Parametric coefficients:

              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
**(Intercept)**                      18.0601     0.8425  21.437  < 2e-16 ***

***postpref1.18228915156431***       4.0094     1.3048   3.073  0.00246 **
```

This number in postpref name is value of 1 (centered and standarized).

Thanks for your help and recommendations!

Roger

EDIT: Thanks for quick answers.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Probably the problem is connected to the code you are running. Please show the code, not just the errors. For example, in factorizing your categorical variables, R tells us you improperly specified a column name - it can't find it. But without seeing the code you ran or your column names, there is little we can do to help.

Comment: How many smooth terms? What are the dimensions of each e.g the `k` value which I think defaults to 10 for univariate smooths? So depending on how you set up your model you may have more coefficients than rows of data --. the first error. So more details are required on the model you are trying to fit please.

Comment: Thx @Gregor. Code provided. It's enough?

Comment: Thx @user20650. Yes, I'm running (before test alternative variables, as smoothing level or dimensions (k)) the default parameters. Once the code runs properly, I want to check both variables.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues here...

#### Issue 1

You have 43 potential covariates and only 180 observations. What do you possibly hope to achieve by using all 43 covariates in a model with only 180 observations to estimate their effects from? Even for a linear Gaussian model I'd think you were stretching the limits with these data (unless you applied some for of regularization). But you are compounding the problem by then assuming that the relationship between the response and each covariate is smooth and potentially non-linear. To do that you are representing each smooth functional effect as a spline basis with *K* basis functions, the default for which is `k = 10` but with the identifiability constraint because of the model constant term, means *each covariate* has **9** basis functions and hence **9** coefficients, which is considerably more coefficients than data: (9 * 41) + 2 + 1 = 372

The error message is telling you exactly this point; that you are trying to estimate more coefficients than you have data. That it works up to 22 covariates is likely due to (9 * 20) + 2 + 1 = 183 coefficient which is fewer than the number of data.

You simply cannot do what you are trying to do with that many covariates represented as smooth functions and that few data.

Do you really need all the wiggliness that **9** basis functions per smooth would afford? You could (I think) get away with setting `k = 5` in each of the `s()` terms, which would mean **4** basis functions per smooth, but even then you might not have enough data.

That said, doing this is statistically dubious unless you are fitting the model purely for prediction purposes, and even then I hope you have an independent test set to evaluate the error correctly.

If you really need to do selection like this then it is better to use `select = TRUE` to put an extra penalty on each smooth that acts only on functions in the penalty null space (the functions that are not subject to the smoothness penalty because, in this case, they have 0 second derivative: a linear function). This extra penalty means the model can shrink terms out of a model like a Lasso penalty does.

Even if you do that, this is statistically dubious with so few data; it is odd indeed that you know enough about the effects of these covariates to presume they are non-linear but not enough about the system to know which are important.

If you really need to do this, there are other GAM-like settings for high-dimensional data (in this case covariate dimensions). See the *gamsel* package for one.

#### Issue 2

*mgcv.helper* seems to me to be of limited use here - the examples seem to use all linear terms. Regardless, VIF is not of much use and why this is so is because it is a test for multi**collinearity**. You are fitting non-linear functions. You should be more worried about concurvity, which is the euqivalent but more pernicious problems with non-linear functions as you need to concern yourself with the possibility that one or more functions may be a non-linear function of one or more of the other smooth functions in the model. See `?concurvity`

#### Issue 3

See Issue 2.